# Install caffe on Mac OS X (Catalina)

Tags: gpu, caffe, openpose

I am following the official instructions from http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_osx.html

A couple of things are unclear. Instructions say
"CUDA: Install via the NVIDIA package that includes both CUDA and the bundled driver."
I do not have an Nvidia GPU (am on MacBook Pro 2016 which has amd gpu instead) and plan to use caffe with CPU only.

a) do I have to install CUDA in order to install caffe?

b) inside Makefile.config it have uncommented code that asks to set CUDA directory, saying the following:

# CUDA directory contains bin/ and lib/ directories that we need.

CUDA_DIR := /usr/local/cuda

Seems to suggest that I should have CUDA. It was my impression that I can't have CUDA without Nvidia gpu. (My ultimate goal is to install and work with OpenPose from Spyder.)
Why do I need CUDA uncommented when I am specifying that it will be CPU only

# CPU-only switch (uncomment to build without GPU support).

CPU_ONLY := 1

---

So far I have left CUDA commands uncommented as they were and proceeded with `make all` caffe compilation from terminal. I am encountering the following error and not sure how to solve it. Anyone managed please?

```
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0
ld: framework not found vecLib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0] Error 1
```

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing Xcode command line tools but that did not help. Now I am trying to find the file from which a call to search for vecLib.framework is made, so that I can edit that file and set the vecLib path correctly. I have found it under Library/Developer section. Does anyone know which file is being used to search for vecLib path?

---

Next problem:

```
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0
ld: library not found for -lboost_python3
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0] Error 1
```

I uncommented this line in Makefile.config as per instructions I was following

```
PYTHON_LIBRARIES := boost_python3 python3.7m
```

Not sure how to resolve the missing -lboost_python3.
I found and can see the directory of boost_python3 but don't know how/where I shall use it?

Comment: I won't be able to give you complete instructions, but you should not attempt to install CUDA on your laptop, it won't work, there is no point or benefit, and it will only confuse things.  It is [possible to run caffe without a (CUDA) GPU](https://sandeeppalakkal.wordpress.com/2016/07/09/installation-of-caffe-on-cpu-only-without-gpu/)  Yes, I am aware those instructions are not Mac-oriented.

Comment: Thank you @RobertCrovella your comment was helpful. I have just left all CUDA commands untouched inside Makefile.config file. Still do not understand why they are uncommented but maybe someone else can shed light on this.

I then followed instructions from the following link on how to fill Makefile.config for MAC with CPU caffe installation only using Anaconda3: https://gist.github.com/chtlp/2b526d7953576d262ee4903a0de1b4f2 

I have had many errors upon running <make all> but had to further configure my Makefile.config file.

Comment: I have resolved framework not found vecLib by amending the following line of code in Makefile: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/6751/files